# Regarding CPU utilization by a given process SNMP

Tags: cpu-usage, snmp, net-snmp, process-monitoring

I have a multiprocessor system and I am trying to calculate CPU usage of a particular process, But I am getting more than 100%
Later I saw the hrSWRunPerf object's properties of that OID ([hrSWRunPerfCPU](https://help.genesys.com/pureconnect/mergedprojects/wh_tr/mergedprojects/wh_tr_snmp/desktop/hrswrunperf_objects.htm)) from  which is

| Type | Access | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Integer32 | read-only | The number of centi-seconds of the total system's CPU resources consumed by this process. Note that on a multi-processor system, this value may increment by more than one centi-second in one centi-second of real (wall clock) time. |

Hence how do I get to calculate CPU usage(%) of a process in the case of a multi-processor machine?

Comment: `hrSWRunPerfCPU` can't be translated into usage % without more context. It is time spent by CPU by executing process, so at least you need to know some time period. Maybe you can figure out when process started and do some simple math, which will tell you how many % of that time period was spent in your process.Then divide by number of CPU cores.

Comment: Can I do this ((hrSWRunPerfCPU value / 100) / system uptime seconds)*100 to get usage in percentage

Comment: Is your process running from system uptime? If not (which is likely), then result will not be something that you want.

Comment: You don't need to have a specific time such as uptime. you have to sample the values at various times. So if you have a set polling interval of 5 minutes, you sample the values at those times then divide it by the period. Having multiprocess will likely show you over 100%, but that can be seen as 100% per CPU, so 200% is 2 full CPU's used. but if you want to see the usage of overall percentage used, then divide by the number of processors.

Comment: correction on my last comment, I meant muti-processor, not process.

Comment: Its working fine in Linux but still getting over 100% in Windows.